# Python error: need more than one value to unpack

Tags: python

Ok, so I'm learning Python. But for my studies I have to do rather complicated stuff already. I'm trying to run a script to analyse data in excel files. This is how it looks:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

#lots of functions, not relevant

resultsdir = /home/blah

filename1=sys.argv[1]
filename2=sys.argv[2]
out = open(sys.argv[3],"w")

#filename1,filename2="CNVB_reads.403476","CNVB_reads.403447"

file1=open(resultsdir+"/"+filename1+".csv")
file2=open(resultsdir+"/"+filename2+".csv")

for line in file1:
    start.p,end.p,type,nexons,start,end,cnvlength,chromosome,id,BF,rest=line.split("\t",10)
    CNVs1[chr].append([int(start),int(end),float(BF)])

for line in file2:
    start.p,end.p,type,nexons,start,end,cnvlength,chromosome,id,BF,rest=line.split("\t",10)
    CNVs2[chr].append([int(start),int(end),float(BF)])
```

These are the titles of the columns of the data in the excel files and I want to split them, I'm not even sure if that is necessary when using data from excel files.

```
#more irrelevant stuff

out.write(filename1+","+filename2+","+str(chromosome)+","+str(type)+","+str(shared)+"\n")
```

This is what it should write in my output, 'shared' is what I have calculated, the rest is already in the files.

Ok, now my question, finally, when I call the script like that:
python script.py CNVB_reads.403476 CNVB_reads.403447 script.csv in my shell

I get the following error message:

```
start.p,end.p,type,nexons,start,end,cnvlength,chromosome,id,BF,rest=line.split("\t",10)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have no idea what is meant by that in relation to the data... Any ideas?

Comment: It means your line doesn't have 11 values that are seperated by tabs. It apparently only has one

Comment: Sounds like `line.split("\t",10)` returns a lost of only one element.

Comment: You should really use the `csv` module for splitting CSV (or misnamed tab-separated files with a .csv extension for some unholy reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `line.split('\t', 10)` call did not return eleven elements. Perhaps it is empty?

You probably want to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead to parse these files.

```
import csv
import os

for filename, target in ((filename1, CNVs1), (filename2, CNVs2)):
    with open(os.path.join(resultsdir, filename + ".csv"), 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            start.p, end.p = row[:2]
            BF = float(row[8])
            target[chr].append([int(start), int(end), BF])
```

Comment: I tried using the csv module now, but I get an error again saying: too many values to unpack...

Comment: @user2112896: Print out the `row` when that happens. `try: start.py, end.p = row[:2]` `except ValueError: print "Not enough values? Row:", row`

Comment: @user2112896: Don't unpack the row in the loop; your file has *more* than 5 columns in each row, so that unpack will not work. Why not use my version instead?